# Issue to place 2 lines of text in a circle

Tags: html, css

I'd like to place a seconf line of text below the word "State". For some reason the second line of text ("of mind" in red) is placed way below the circle. Do you know what is causing this huge gap and how to fix it? Use of 
 was not appropriate? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/7txCN/26/

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="circle text color-2 color2-box-shadow">
    State<br> <span>of Mind</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /* text styling */
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    color: #FFF;  border: 2px solid #fff;
    line-height: 220px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.color-1 { background: #DD4814;}
.color-2 { background: #AEA79F; }
.color-3 { background: #5E2750; }
.color1-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814 }
.color2-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #AEA79F }
.color3-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750 }
.circle span { 
color: red;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Comment: It's caused by the monster line-height.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `line-height` vertical center technique doesn't work with multiple lines of text.

If the height and width of the circle are fixed, then create some of the height with the top and bottom padding to center the text in the middle.

The `<br>` can be removed if the span is given `display: block`.

### Working Example

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* text styling */
  font-size: 45px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 80px;
  padding: 70px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.color-1 {
  background: #DD4814;
}
.color-2 {
  background: #AEA79F;
}
.color-3 {
  background: #5E2750;
}
.color1-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814
}
.color2-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #AEA79F
}
.color3-box-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750
}
.circle span {
  color: red;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="circle text color-2 color2-box-shadow">

  State <span>of Mind</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a slightly improved structure without any bare text nodes.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7txCN/31/)

**HTML**

*NB. No break tags needed.*

```
<div class="circle text color-2 color2-box-shadow">
    <div class="text-wrap"> 
        <span>State</span> 
        <span>of Mind</span>
    </div>
</div
```

With this CSS

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /* text styling */
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: relative;
}
.color-1 {
    background: #DD4814;
}
.color-2 {
    background: #AEA79F;
}
.color-3 {
    background: #5E2750;
}
.color1-box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814
}
.color2-box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #AEA79F
}
.color3-box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750
}
.text-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.text-wrap span {
    display: block;
}
.circle span:nth-child(2) {
    color: red;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```css
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    /* text styling */
    font-size: 45px;
    width: 220px;
    height: 220px;
    color: #FFF;  border: 2px solid #fff;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.color-1 { background: #DD4814;}
.color-2 { background: #AEA79F; }
.color-3 { background: #5E2750; }
.color1-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #DD4814 }
.color2-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #AEA79F }
.color3-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750 }
.circle span { 
color: red;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle text color-2 color2-box-shadow">
    State<br> <span>of Mind</span>
</div>
```